# JSON date format seems different

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, c#-4.0

I have a datatable and I export it to JSON format. One column of datatable is a date column, like 2013-01-09 02:18:11.117.

When I export it, it seems like `"Date":"\/Date(1357690691117)\/"`

My code is below:

```
DataTable dataTable = GetData();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                  Select(column => column.ColumnName);
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(seperator, columnNames));

foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(seperator, fields));
}

return sb.ToString();
```

Why does the date column seem different?

Answer (score 2):

See the Stack Overflow question *[Format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/)*:

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
```

Stack Overflow question *[The "right" JSON date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204)* is more specific and direct to your question.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Ok, please enlighten me. How would you put "Sets the default radix, in the range 2 to 16, to the value of expression." to use here? Not pulling your leg, I really can't fathom it, and you got an upvote, so I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: @MarjanVenema IE8 : http://i.stack.imgur.com/FpNsr.png

Answer (score 0):

It's auto-conversion:
2013-01-09 02:18:11.117 = "/Date(1357690691117)/" (milliseconds)

For example (conversion to "dd/mm/yyyy" format):

```
function formatJsonDate(jsonDate) {
    return (new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)))).format("dd/mm/yyyy");
};

var test = formatJsonDate('/Date(1357690691117)/');
```